# Check for required fields of an arbitrary input object

Tags: typescript

I use TypeScript in AWS Lambdas. Input objects provided for such Lambdas can be arbitrary. I always need to check if all required fields are provided in the input. I need to provide an error message explicitly saying which fields are missing if this is the case. If all required fields are provided, I need to cast the object into a domain object defined as an interface. Here an example of how this can be done:

```
interface Car {
  wheels: string
  doors: string
  engine: string
}

export const checkIfCar = (maybeCar: Partial<Car>): Car | { error: string } => {
  if (maybeCar.wheels == null) {
    return { error: 'Car should have wheels' };
  } else {
    if (maybeCar.doors == null) {
      return { error: 'Car should have doors' };
    } else {
      if (maybeCar.engine == null) {
        return { error: 'Car should have an engine' }
      } else {
        const car: Car = {
          wheels: maybeCar.wheels,
          doors: maybeCar.doors,
          engine: maybeCar.engine
        }
        return car
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While this works perfectly well, there is a lot of nesting and boiler plate happening. Is there a TypeScript native way to achieve the same, but in a more concise way? If not, is there a library which takes care of this pattern? I imagine this is a common issue not only I am dealing with.

I am aware of [User defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). However this requires that the guard function is updated each time a new field is added, which can easily be forgotten. It also does not solve the issue of telling me which fields are missing. I am looking for a way where all fields of an object are checked for existence automatically.

Comment: You mean in runtime? If so, typescsript has nothing to do with it because it runs only on build time. If in runtime, is something like this can help? https://github.com/anthonyshort/ok

Comment: The check itself is surely at runtime. But of course the result of the validation needs to be typed. So in case of a valid object I need to follow a code path which would be clearly defined with the type `Car` in this case. The library you provided seems to be js, so the result will not be typed I imagine.

Comment: `But of course the result of the validation needs to be typed` at runtime, there is no typescript, only javascript, so it can't be "typed"..

Comment: Yes, but in my TS code I can distinguish if the check was successful, then it will return something which corresponds to type `Car` (having all the fields), or not. And this is code written in ts, which is typed. It is basically what I wrote already as example. The boiler plate behind this check is something I don't want to write every time. Both provided answers below are actually giving solutions for that exact issue.

Comment: The thing is that you don't care about the types while validating in runtime. I mean, you'd like to have a function `isValid(object)` so you don't have to deal neither the types nor the validation. Anyway, [`yup`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#typescript-support) is another library which validate schema and has a good typescript support so the schema basically generated from the types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript has no builtin feature for runtime type checking or validation. I'm also guessing that your problem doesn't get solved with a simple `!== null` check. What if it's `undefined`? What if `engine` is an object and not a string?

Luckily there are several libraries you can use for runtime validation and some of them cooperate very nicely with TypeScript. One such library is [`runtypes`](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes). For your purposes, you can use it in this manner:

```js
import * as runtypes from "runtypes";

const CarType = runtypes.Record({
  wheels: runtypes.String,
  doors: runtypes.String,
  engine: runtypes.String,
});

type Car = runtypes.Static<typeof CarType>;
```

Now you can use `CarType.check(maybeCar)`.

Other alternatives are [`zod`](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod), [`io-ts`](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts), and [`class-validator`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator), each with their particular ways of doing essentially the same thing.

For more complex validation tasks I've also used JSON schema + [`json-schema-to-typescript`](https://github.com/bcherny/json-schema-to-typescript#readme) along with a JSON schema checker, such as [`AJV`](https://ajv.js.org/). It takes longer to setup but it is the ultimate validation + static typing tool in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need of checking the types of the fields as well. `CarType.validate(obj)` is exactly what I was looking for. I will start using `runtype` to reduce the boiler plate described above.

Comment: Btw. we are using protobuf for schema definition, so AJV would unfortunately not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Possible answer using an automatical way to check.

Unfortunately you need to provide the keys of the properties to check.

[snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJysg3gKGcgdwAsIIAbALmQGcwpQBzAbj2QBMB7DqK2+kZqwgDQEXnUYsAvjhwIOIWmgwBpCAE9qyALzIA2qwDkxUmUMAaI524WjwhqNsBdFjjDqADigCiUKNwAlCDAdbGQhP25xfkEpV3lFEIQSBABrAEkYdExdAAoAWzh1ACMIbKpcfD1UjWRQZBr1DhhlKCcAfmjGZAAfZBAAVzIyaQBKKmze5F9-KCCQ7QA+bFYoYIGoEFa1TQA6NbYBpFzcsHyPc2QAD1GdZcr8ZASlRqpG5tbQq+Q4LXeW7KuR7IAD0IOQZAgcAAbhAtHABmAOIUwMAEHBhuo6i0CCgMWs4GwsTAOAMQGwfltoLNWPhgC1coZqTY6lszh5bg9gWswBs2ecWMCZMDaaDwagUqlkCTMGASMh8sBqNRumw4GA4KL6cgCkVStlqhonDptLpoRxgBSAAy9HoAAsKJTKGEN6mNpt0g2GnNF+B5fJWwOBzJ4yAABpNqERSWQKUQYSgACRYK5SMOWIPIOKimSi9mu90KvXOqAFn5aPiSWTc9abZDswVZy5YKTlnWTPozQLBUajaSyZ4cSG7MgcBi5ZIQNKZbK5B4mchUQy2fDWUPLyxSXvxBTUIcQEdjieSmcYOesBeUZAb1hrqhesgZ5D2URL2xbvsD3f7w-jyfTrIz3nEhF2vFd2C4ddwJfEAxDAzdtyAA)

```
interface Car {
  wheel: string;
  door: string;
  engine: string;
}

const CarKeys = [
  'wheel',
  'door',
  'engine',
];

type ErrorRet = { 
  error: string;
};

const checkIfCar = (maybeCar: {
  [key in keyof Car]?: string | null;
}): Car | ErrorRet => {
  return CarKeys.reduce((tmp, x) => {
    const key: keyof Car = x as keyof Car;

    // leaves automatically if we already found an error
    if ('error' in tmp) {
      return tmp;
    }
    
    // Check for the missing data
    if (maybeCar[key] === void 0 || maybeCar[key] === null) {
      return {
        error: `Car should have ${x}`,
      };
    }

    tmp[key] = maybeCar[key] as string;

    return tmp;
  }, {} as (Car | ErrorRet));
}

console.log(checkIfCar({
  wheel: '',
  door: '',
}));

console.log(checkIfCar({
  wheel: '',
  door: null,
  engine: '',
}));

console.log(checkIfCar({
  wheel: '',
  door: '',
  engine: '',
}));
```